# If an integer is randomly chosen among the first 50 positive integers, what is the probability that the chosen integer will be a 2-digit number?

Tags: probability

I thought that this question would simply be that there are 40 2-digit integers so you have a $\frac{40}{50}$ chance of getting a 2-digit integer via relative frequency.

However the answer says that it is 0.82, and it doesn’t show any work. Am I thinking about this problem in the wrong way?

Comment: That's because there are forty-one positive integers between $1$ and $50$ inclusive.

Comment: There are only $9$ positive one-digit integers

Comment: I think you meant, Lord Shark, that there are forty-one *two-digit* positive integers between 1 and 5 inclusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two-digit numbers between $1$ and $50$ are from $10$ to $50$ (both included). This amounts to $41$ numbers to choose from. Hence probability will be ${41\over 50}$.